# class whose instance is Map not Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make `class` whose **instance** will be a `Map`
Here's what i've tried:

```
class Element {
    constructor(name, buildYear) {
        this.set('name', name);
        this.set('buildYear', buildYear);
    }
}

let test = new Map();
test = test Element('Park', 1998);
```

For making an **object** we use `test = new Element('Park', 1998)`
How can i do this for **Map**

Thanks.

Comment: What is `test Element` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can extend the Map class

```js
class Element extends Map {
    constructor(name, buildYear) {
        super()
        this.set('name', name);
        this.set('buildYear', buildYear);
    }
}


let test = new Element('Park', 1998);

console.log(test.get('name'))
```